# Pig Setup on windows in local mode

Tags: apache-pig

1. I have downloaded pig-0.11.1 from apache website
2. Installed cygwin with perl package
3. Installed Latest Java
4. Added pig.../bin to PATH

   *D:>PATH
   PATH=D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32 \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\pig-0.11.1\bin*

Now, if I run pig -help,

```
'pig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Have I missed any step?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening 'sh' and enter the pig commands. (i.e.) type 'sh' in the command prompt , it will open a shell like below image and enter your pig commands.

[image]